# Youtube Data API v. 3 - Display channel author name of private / deleted video

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

This is one of them Youtube internal decisions that is highly counter-productive. Correct me if I'm wrong, but they currently don't want to expose the channel name of private / deleted videos. They even call it a 'bug' if it happens ( http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5893 ). So what happens if I solely request video IDs that were public beforehand but then later became private or deleted? I will get, via usage of Youube Data API v3, a "response is undefined" error message in console. WHat happens when that message happens? My code breaks!

This is the code I currently use:

```
function DisplayThemVideos(yeah) {
var yeah = $("#ThoseMissingIDs").text();
var vidrequestOptions = {
id: yeah,
part: 'snippet',
fields: 'items(id),items(snippet(channelId)),items(snippet(channelTitle)),
items(snippet(title)),items(snippet(thumbnails(default)))'
};

var vidrequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list(vidrequestOptions);
vidrequest.execute(function(response) {
var videoIdItems = response.result.items;
if (videoIdItems) { // If results
displayResults(videoIdItems);
} else { // if NO results
alert('Sawwy, YouLose, thx to Youtube!'); // This alert never fires!
}
});
}
```

Now the undefined "response" is actually an empty request sent back to my app from Youtube server. Youtube answers back with an empty "item" tag which obviously doesn't help much for the `displayResults(videoIdItems)` function which gets fired without any item to display! They should at least let the channel name and channel ID filter through so a User could click on a link in order to access the remaining public videos of that channel (wouldn't that be productive Jeff P?).

SO my dilemma is to get the `else` section working like so:

```
displayResults(videoIdItems);
} else { // if NO results or if results return EMPTY or response "undefined"
alert('Sorry pal but these IDs ___________ are currently missing.
Click the Channel link to access the public videos of that channel.');
}
```

The `else` part works as it should for similar API calls as demonstrated in Youtube Data API v.3 sample code, but I guess it currently isn't able to handle empty requests.

So what am I to do? WIll I have to use an ajax call with success fail error handling? Like I said beforehand, the API returns an empty request so the response is legit but the response content comes empty for private/deleted videos, hence, "undefined" with code breaking along the wway.

Any hints leading to a working solution would help! Thx for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only partly answer my question. Easiest is to use `Catch` of `Try - Catch` method which detects everything except syntax errors, helpful in detecting an empty response (undefined) and activating your function that can access the Youtube player for displaying current availability status of the missing ID:

```
...

var vidrequest = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list(vidrequestOptions);
vidrequest.execute(function(response) {

try {
var videoIdItems = response.result.items;
if (videoIdItems) { // If results
displayResults(videoIdItems);
return false;
}

} catch (e) {
// put code here that handles errors such as empty or undefined response
// which otherwise breaks your code

} finally {
// optionally, put code here that will always trigger
}

});
```

Hope this helps others.